# ArrayList<String> objects point to null. Why?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a piece of code that takes in an `ArrayList<String>` object and eventually takes that object and adds it to a `HashMap` object as the key. When I print the hashmap, the key's are all null while the values are correct.

I already know I can fix the code by passing in a copy of the `ArrayList<String>` object and that fixes my issue (i.e. `buildHash(new ArrayList<String>(key))`. But why does it point to null otherwise?

```java
HashMap<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>> hash = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<String> key = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i <= 9999999; i++) {
     key.add(//different strings depending on the iteration);
     if ( !hash.contains(key) ) {
          buildHash(key);
     }
     key.clear();
}

private void buildHash(ArrayList<String> key) {
    ArrayList<String> follows = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int index = 0; index <= 9999999; index++) {
         // add stuff to follows...
    }
    hash.put(key, follows);
}
```

I thought that the value of the key would be added to the hash, and the hash's keys would point to the value it was before it was cleared by `key.clear()`. That way I could reuse key over and over without creating another object in memory.

I'm new to Java (and coding) so I'm probably naive, but I thought I could save memory by utilizing the mutability of `ArrayLists` as opposed to `Lists` as the number of operations and key's generated for this project are well into the millions, if not more. Is there no avoiding that? And if not, is there any other optimization I could do?

Comment: What do you think `key.clear()` does? And do you really want to use an array as your hash key? It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, and less clear what you think you're doing in the code. Trying to "save memory" at this stage is likely a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 1):

As documented, `ArrayList::clear` removes all elements from the list. So you are wiping out the content.

> utilizing the mutability of ArrayLists

Exactly what you do *not* want in a key. An object used as a key in a map should never be modifiable, not in a way that affects the outcome of the hash value calculation or affects the outcome of the `equals` method. Would you expect to find someone in a phone book after they changed their name?

It hard for me to imagine where you would ever want to use a list as a key in a map.

As for trying to “save memory”… don’t. The last thing a new programmer should worry about is conserving RAM. Write simple code, easy to read, easy to edit. Then let the JVM do the optimizing work for you.

I suggest you not try so hard at being clever. Spend some time looking at other code. Search Stack Overflow and elsewhere to find code similar to your logic problem or the classes you are using. Then study code samples.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! 

I'm actually doing a project to randomly generate text based of a training text. The keys are to store sequences of words and the values are the words that are most likely to come after that sequence. I can post the full code if you'd like.

Also, it's not so much about being clever as it was trying to think about how to create the best solution, so in that regard, thanks for letting me know about how mutability in keys can be an issue. That's not something I was taught when learning about hashmaps.